# Realm - IncorrectThreadException() when thread is not changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

Why the exception is thrown? At what point the thread is changed in this trace?

0.

[image: Realm IncorrectThreadException]

1.
[image: Realm IncorrectThreadException2]

2.

[image: Realm IncorrectThreadException3]

3.
[image: Realm IncorrectThreadException]

Comment: I think you error is because you're trying to execute the transaction in the `executeAsyncBlock`, so that block is moving the transaction to another thread. What about removing the block? Have you tried it?

Comment: @Orlando thank you for your comment. The error happens occasionally. The whole app is heavily async. Do you think, `refresh` is called on a different thread, rather than `defaultRealm` (it seems not)? This is what important.

Comment: I think the issue is related to that fact. Check out the code example included in the docs: https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#using-a-realm-across-threads Maybe that implementation will work for you. In that example Realm is performing a million-document write transaction in async mode.

Comment: @Orlando what is the difference between the snippet you provided link to and the code I shared?

Comment: How are you defining (or from where are you importing) this `executeAsyncBlock`, @kerd ?

Comment: @Orlando, please, see updated question.

Comment: I see it now, @kerd I think your problem is the `dispatch_async();` You're moving the transaction from the process executing the block (from where you're creating the Realm) to the async `_queue` in your first screenshot. Why is that? Is this task a heavy load to the process or is it taking too long?

Comment: Hmm, the only thing I can potentially think of is that you're executing a block, inside another block, which might be confusing the ownership of the objects. Have you tried passing that block directly to the `dispatch_async` function call and moving the `@autoreleasepool` to inside it?

Comment: @TiM thank you for your comment. I have done some further investigation and opened an issue on github. Please, check it out: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4132